# CSS: Two columns - one fixed width; the other to balance of viewport

Tags: html, css, css-position

How does one make a html page with a high bar 100vh wide, and below that two columns? The left-hand column is float left and a fixed width. The right hand column is float right and takes up the balance of the horizontal space, so that the width of the two columns combined is the same as the high bar, that is to say 100vh. The left-hand column sits side-by-side with the right-hand column, with no space between.

I need a css solution, not using tables, nor resorting to javascript. I can use scss for the css, if that helps.

## What I have got so far

Here is as close as I have gotten so far:

```css
header {
  width: 100vh;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: saddlebrown;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
header *  { background-color: chocolate;}
header h1 { text-align: center;}
header p  { text-align: justify;}
  
.two-columns {
  wide: 100vh;
}

.left-column {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  }
  
.right-column {
  float: right;
  width: 70vh;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: green; 
  }
```

```html
<header><h1>This high-bar should be 100vh wide.</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictas eleifend id pro, inermis graecis recteque ut vix. Per invenire eleifend an. Duo vero nemore te, mediocrem vituperata qui eu. Semper numquam ne pri, et eos dico epicuri, cum in dicta oratio. Voluptaria inciderint eum ne, doctus patrioque vituperatoribus ei usu. Ut sed brute perfecto quaerendum, mei duis doming oporteat ea. At eam omittantur vituperatoribus. Sea te nobis euismod persecuti. Id alienum apeirian erroribus his, ad sit magna solum efficiantur, sanctus tibique ut sit. Eum dolorum voluptatibus ex, in eum fuisset insolens.</p>
</header>

<div class="two-columns">
  <div class="left-column">
    <p>This left column is a fixed 300px wide.</p>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484677460604-9c1334e783a1?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=057251dd8afbb9405720551a85f584ae&auto=format&fit=crop&w=300&q=80"/>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <p>This right column should take up the remainder of the space. The width of this bit should be 100vh - 300px - a bit for margins and borders and such.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above solution works or not, depending on the browser or view-port width. Sometimes the right column will incorrectly sit below the image; sometimes it will sit with a gap from the left column.

I put a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/SeanBDurkin/t1efb1u7/56/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with flexbox to do this:

```css
* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

header {
  width: 100vh;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: saddlebrown;
}

header * {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

header h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

header p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.two-columns {
  width: 100vh;
  display:flex;
}

.left-column {
  width: 300px;
}

.right-column {
  flex:1;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: green;
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
 }
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>This high-bar should be 100vh wide.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictas eleifend id pro, inermis graecis recteque ut vix. Per invenire eleifend an. Duo vero nemore te, mediocrem vituperata qui eu. Semper numquam ne pri, et eos dico epicuri, cum in dicta oratio. Voluptaria inciderint eum
    ne, doctus patrioque vituperatoribus ei usu. Ut sed brute perfecto quaerendum, mei duis doming oporteat ea. At eam omittantur vituperatoribus. Sea te nobis euismod persecuti. Id alienum apeirian erroribus his, ad sit magna solum efficiantur, sanctus
    tibique ut sit. Eum dolorum voluptatibus ex, in eum fuisset insolens.</p>
</header>

<div class="two-columns">
  <div class="left-column">
    <p>This left column is a fixed 300px wide.</p>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484677460604-9c1334e783a1?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=057251dd8afbb9405720551a85f584ae&auto=format&fit=crop&w=300&q=80" />
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <p>This right column should take up the remainder of the space. The width of this bit should be 100vh - 300px - a bit for margins and borders and such.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```